# UITabBarController now kills inflight UIKit animations when switches between tabs?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an app that has UITabBarController with two UIViewControllers as its tabs. In the first UIViewController.view  I have a continuous animation with repeat count set to INT_MAX.  It worked fine until 3.2 and 4.0.   On 3.2 or newer, when I switch to a different tab, OS skips to the end of my animations and invokes -animationDidStop:finished:context: on its animation delegate.  Any ideas how to make sure that animations will not be destroyed when tabs are switched?

Comment: I dug deeper on the subject myself. -animationDidStop:finished:context: is being called in 3.1.3 as well. However the animation magically survives the stop call. There is a place for magic in 3.2 or newer too. if I bring modal view-controller over the tab. It is trying to kill the animation, invokes -animationDidStop: but animation still running. The celebration of inconsistency, good job Apple